# Cannot create signature for JWT for APNs

Tags: json, jwt, openssl, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to generate the signature for a JWT using a .p8 private key from Apple for APNs in PHP.

If I try to use the following command `hash_hmac('sha256', $header . '.' . $payload, $key)`, when checking it in Apple's **JSON Web Token Validator**, I get that the signature is invalid.

I have also tried converting the **.p8** private key to a **PEM** file and importing it into the OpenSSL library, but I am still getting the error message `openssl_sign(): Supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key`.

But I generate the JWT using Apple's **JSON Web Token Generator**, everything goes well, even the request to APNs.

Thank you in advance!